# Showing Image when click on image Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, click

I am trying to get a speech bubble up when I click on the image of the person.
How can I do that?

```
<div>
<p style="float: left;"><img src="person.png" border="1px"></p>
</div>

<script>

function bubblespeech()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "../speech.png";
    }
</script>

<img src = "" id = "img"/> 
<onclick="bubble()"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your code seems a bit weird:
Your speech img is empy and you set the source when someone clicks on the image:
I think the better approach would be to have an image with src etc. but it is not displayed an wehen the user clicks on the person image the bubble get displayed.

Also the "onklick" should be in the img-tag of the person

```
<img src="person.png" border="1px" onclick="bubble()">
```

Small example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t20j1nvs/3/):

Comment: that example is exactly what I wanted but it didn't work on mine. I copied the coding and change the file name but when I run it, both image comes up before I click the person

Comment: `<script>
function displayBubble() 
    {
        document.getElementById("bubble").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<img id="wiener" src="person.jpeg" onclick="displayBubble()">

<div id="bubble">
  <img style="width: 150px" src="bubble.png">
  
</div>`

Comment: do you have added the css styles from my example with the right id's for your code? Important is the "display none" for the div with the id "bubble"

Comment: can you please code the "display none" part? i'm not sure how to insert that into `<div id="bubble">`

Comment: i got it! however, i am using Jupyter notebook which does not have CSS. Is there a way to make the bubble display next to person? something along the line float="middle"

Comment: what do you mean with "it does not have css"?
You dont have a .css file or you cant style your page with css?

If you just dont have a .css file you can set all the style in the element or in your html

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp   "Internal Style Sheet" and "Inline Style"